# Дождаться результата redis.get

Tags: ruby, асинхронность, sinatra

Есть функция получения урла:

```
def get_url(short_id)
  redis = EM::Hiredis.connect

  redis.callback do
    redis.get(short_id).callback do |long_url|
      long_url
    end
  end
end
```

Эта функция вызывается из обработчика `sinatra`:

```
get '*' do
  ...
  long_url = get_url(short_id)

  if long_url.nil?
    'not found'
  else
    redirect long_url
  end
end
```

Обработчик, как я понимаю, может вернуть только конкретное значение.
В `long_url` при вызове присваивается объект коллбэка.
Могу ли я вернуть из функции get_url результирующее значение?
Или приостановить выполнение функции до получения результата уже в обработчике?

Используется [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine), не смог найти в документации способа дождаться результата. Возможно, я не правильно подошел к решению задачи.
Используется веб-сервер [Thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/), который также работает на EventMachine.

Буду рад любым подсказкам, благодарю заранее.

---

#### UPD

Наткнулся на [замечательный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993386/async-requests-using-sinatra-streaming-api), в котором описывается работа с `async_sinatra` и возможность удержания соединения открытым по необходимости.

Осталось только понять как сделать корректный с открытым стримом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил это с помощью [async_sinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra)

```
require 'em-hiredis'
require 'sinatra/async'

class ... < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Async

  aget '*' do
    ...

    request = redis.get(short_id)

    request.callback do |long_url|
      if long_url.nil?
        body 'not_found'
      else
        status 301
        headers['Location'] = long_url
        body nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```